# Why use getDerivedStateFromProps instead of componentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs

As read in [this React Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12310) I see more and more that

> the cost of `render()` is relatively small

**In React 16.3**, I'm wondering why one would use the new getDerivedStateFromProps instead of componentDidUpdate?

Imagine this example:

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (!prevState.isModalOpen && nextProps.isReady) {
       return { isModalOpen: true };
  }
}
```

versus

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (!prevState.isModalOpen && this.props.isReady) {
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
  }
}
```

The later seems simpler just because it's using only existing API and looks just like what we used to do in componentWillReceiveProps so I don't see why users would go for getDerivedStateFromProps? What's the benefit?

Thanks!

Comment: Got me wondering this as well. It seems like a single convenient method for doing the same logic in the init of the component and the update of component. In React 15 i have written a number of components that calls the same function in the constructor & CWP. Where as this acts as that single function for you. https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/960305777968930816

Comment: Ok I think you're right, as this is called on init, whereas cDU is called only after render. But I believe the only difference between the two functions is that there is 1 more render if you do things in cDU.

Answer (score 37):

So [Dan Abramov answered on Twitter](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/977181473424932864) and it seems like there are 2 reasons why you should use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead of `componentDidUpdate` + `setState`:

> setState in componentDidUpdate causes an extra render (not directly perceptible to user but it slows down your app). And your render method can’t assume the state is ready (because it won’t be the first time).

- Performance reason: it avoids unnecessary re-render.
- As `getDerivedStateFromProps` is called before rendering on init, you can initialise your state in this function instead of having a constructor to do so.
  Currently you had to have a constructor or `componentWillMount` to init your state before initial rendering.

Comment: But only use getDerivedPropsFromState if you are setting props to state no?

Comment: @zero_cool yes. Anything that isn't to return the new state should go into componentDidMount as said by Dan Abramov in the comment below.

Answer (score 2):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is actually replacement for `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidMount` is not going to be deprecated.

I'm pretty sure it was the community that decided to make a static method with that name.

The reason for this change is that [`componentWillReceiveProps` was one of the methods that led to confusion and further to some memory leaks in user applications](https://deploy-preview-587--reactjs.netlify.com/blog/2018/03/20/react-v-16-3.html#component-lifecycle-changes):

> Many of these issues are exacerbated by a subset of the component
>   lifecycles (componentWillMount, componentWillReceiveProps, and
>   componentWillUpdate). These also happen to be the lifecycles that
>   cause the most confusion within the React community. For these
>   reasons, we are going to deprecate those methods in favor of better
>   alternatives.

Here's the [Dan Abramov tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/953449501448179712) that also makes this more clear:

> However, this means that we’ll part our ways with
>   componentWillReceiveProps() in 17. We think getDerivedStateFromProps()
>   does the same job better and is less confusing. It also happens that
>   cWRP() really messes up our plans for data fetching features that
>   might be in pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations but I think this doesn't really answer my question of why I should use it instead of just putting that logic inside `componentDidMount` and forget about that new function?

Comment: @Grsmto Your assumptions are wrong :) Where does it say that you should use 
`getDerivedStateFromProps` instead of `componentDidUpdate` ? Because these are two different hook methods.

Comment: But why they introduced this function then if I can do the exact same thing in `componentDidMount`? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: it has nothing to do with `componentDidUpdate` both are called at different step of the component lifecycle and will have different use cases. They introduced `getDerivedStateFromProps` to avoid confusion and leave just one method instead of three.

Comment: The fact that `getDerivedStateFromProps` is static causes a problem. If you need the props to fetch information to set the state, how can I do  for a specific component instance without global variables (which would, then, be non-instance specific)?

Comment: You shouldn't be fetching anything in `getDerivedStateFromProps`. That's what `componentDidUpdate` or `componentDidMount` are for.

Comment: Furthermore, with async mode, React may call multiple times the `getDerivedStateFromProps` method instead of the `componentDidMount/Update` methods. (So no fetching into `getDerivedStateFromProps`)
 https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects